# Scala - filter Some's that fail certain condition

Tags: scala

Given a `UserRepository`:

```
class UserRepository {

  val collection = Mongo.connect("users")

  def findBy(key: String, value: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
    collection.flatMap(
      _.find(document(key -> value)).one[User]
    )
  }
}
```

And I want to write a `login` method:

```
def login(email: String, password: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  repo.findBy("email", email)
    // .filter { user => BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password) }
}
```

How would I write a mapping on the result of `findBy` to transform all `Some(user)`'s into `None`'s if they fail the test `BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password)` ? Is there some kind of transform I can do to turn any of the `Some`'s that fail that check into `None`'s?

Comment: Can't you just use the `filter`-method that you have commented out? What is the problem with it?

Comment: The issue with going straight into a filter is the value is either a `Some` or a `None`, so simply doing `BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password)` throws:

`Compilation error[value password is not a member of Option[authentication.User]]`

Comment: Granted, I could do a match inside filter, I was just wondering if there was anything nicer than pattern-matching to use here? Feels a bit odd to perform a pattern match to then just return another `Option` (that may just be my train of thought and it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do in this situation)

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay enough attention to the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use collect and use the pattern matching guard to check the user. If user fails then return a None

```
findBy(key, value).collect {
  case Some(user) if ! BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password) =>  None
}
```

Suggestion

It would be good to collect user which satisfy the condition this way your final output type would be `Future[user]` instead of `Future[Option[User]]`. Of course after the above collect your `Future[Option[User]]` would contain `Some(user)` where is the `user` is valid user.

```
findBy(key, value).collect {
  case Some(user) if BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password) =>  user
}
```

The line gives only valid users and the final type would be `Future[User]` instead of `Future[Option[User]]`

Comment: What happens if there is no user that matches the `findBy`?

Comment: @danbroooks it will give you `None`

Comment: @danbroooks `Future` will have `None` in it. as usuall in the first case and in the second case you will get `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Of course exception will be wrapped inside the Future. Choose which ever you want to use.

Comment: @f.g I like your implementation as it uses all scala's features. It looks hell of lot cleaner and less terrifying. Also easy to debug and less chances of bugs

Answer (score 3):

You need to map over the `Future` to transform its value from a `Some` to a `None`. The call to filter needs to go inside the function passed to the map-function. Try this:

```
def login(email: String, password: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    repo.findBy("email", email)
        .map { userOpt => userOpt.filter(user => BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password)) }
}
```

Comment: f . g's answer is cleaner though. At least this shows what was wrong with your initial attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to do `filter`/`collect` on the `Future` because you'll get a failed Future (with exception), and then you need to `.recover` etc. Because result of your operation is already stated in it's signature (`Option[User]`) you probably want this:

```
repo.findBy("email", email).map { userOpt =>
  val maybeUser1 = userOpt.filter { user => BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password) }

  // or like this:
  // longer form, if more than one options or whatever
  val maybeUser2 = for {
    user <- userOpt
    if(BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.password))
  } yield user
}
```

Comment: With this I get `type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[authentication.User]]
 required: Option[authentication.User]`

Comment: Then `findBy("email", email).**flatMap**`? xD

Comment: Then I get `type mismatch;
 found   : Option[authentication.User]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]` :/

Comment: But my method signature is: `def login(email: String, password: String): Option[User]`